# How often do Feebas and Manaphy appear?

Tags: magikarp-jump

In Magikarp Jump, there is a chance of encountering Feebas or Manaphy while feeding Magikarp at the pond.

When tapped, Manaphy will start a food frenzy, while Feebas gives Magikarp a boost in JP.

**How often do Manaphy and Feebas appear? Is their appearance randomized?**

Comment: Somewhat related meta question: [Is adding some image for flavor out of the rules?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12330/145980) The main point of the accepted answer is that if you're going to add an image, it should be 1) related, 2) necessary to explain the question. The people who play Magikarp Jump (i.e., the people who would be answering this question) can reasonably be assumed to know who Manaphy and Feebas are without the image, so it isn't really necessary.

Comment: @MageXy There's over 1000 Pokemon so a picture definitely helps identification! It's not like Steven posted some dank memes like in the meta example you linked. Furthermore, visitors with no experience with Pokemon would benefit greatly from pictures.

Comment: @LateralTerminal There's not 1000 Pokemon in Magikarp Jump. In fact, when I last played, there was like 25 at most. And given the context (they appear in the feeding pond), it's quite obvious which Pokemon he's asking about, because those were the only two tappable Pokemon that would swim by. Maybe things have changed since then (and if so, then perhaps a picture would be helpful), but at the time it wasn't really needed.

Comment: @MageXy This post [used to have an embedded image](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/314977/revisions), but I removed it after I was told it was unnecessary.

Comment: @MageXy Sorry I meant 1000 Pokemon in general. I only played magikarp jump for one day.  I still think for any Pokemon game pictures are very useful for new players. Not so much for experienced players.

Answer (score 2):

These are simply random events. So, yes, their occurrences are randomized.

From [here](http://techknower.com/magikarp-jump-events-guide/):

> Feebas will randomly appear in your aquarium.
>
> Just like Feebas, Manaphy will randomly [appear] in your aquarium.

According to [Bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon:_Magikarp_Jump#Random_encounter_events), both of these events can randomly occur **during feeding**, but this is the only source to say this. All other sources simply say it occurs at any time while at the pond.

According to [PokemonGoHub](https://pokemongohub.net/magikarp-jump/event-guide/) both of these events can randomly occur at any time while viewing the Home screen:

> Randomly occurs when viewing the home screen

This is also explained in [this IGN article](http://m.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-magikarp-jump/Events):

> Can occur anytime at the pond

In order to trigger the bonuses these events provide, you must tap on the event Pokémon.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro the event is them appearing, not you tapping on them... but regardless, I'm not sure how these work differently based on everything I'm seeing. They simply appear during feeding as opposed to only showing up after training sessions, etc. These two events are **random** events. There are no specific triggers.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Correlation does not equate to causation. The event has occurred for you when you tap, but as the sources mentioned, it may happen at any time.

Comment: Just to add my own experience: If I don't access the game for about a day, the next time I play - without exception - I've seen at least one (usually both) of the Pokemon within 5-10 seconds of starting to feed my Magikarp. So I would *speculate* that the random chance is continually calculated throughout the day, and if you trigger the appearance anytime during the day, they will show up the next time you go to your tank.